# SQL - Return record with a null value only if there is no matching record that is not null

Tags: sql, null, distinct

I have a table that has some multiple entries for certain fields but not others. Here's an illustration:

[image]

I need to write a query that will return a distinct list of the 'Type' values with the numeric value if a non-null record exists, but with the null value only if there is no matching 'Type' value with a corresponding numeric value. So, for the table above, I need a recordset like this:

[image]

I thought this would be easy, but I've been scratching my head over it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select type, max(col2)
from t
group by type;
```

This guarantees that only one row is returned for each value in the first column and you only get `NULL` when all the values are `NULL`.

If you want *all* non-null values and a representative `NULL` one of the others do not exist, you can use logic like this:

```
select type, col2
from t
where col2 is not null
union al
select type, null
from t
group by type
having max(col2) is null;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks much.